# I would like to calculate the value with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm a programming beginner.

I have an XLSXFILE to calculate some value by using equations. So, I wrote the code like below.

```
import openpyxl
import math

#Load file
XLSFILE = r"C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\Project_name\test.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(XLSFILE, data_only=True)
ws_template = wb["Sheet1"]

#fill in value
for i in range (0, 61):
    Ec = ws_template.cell(row=i+1, column=1)
    Fc = -34.5*(2*(Ec/-0.002)-math.pow(Ec/-0.002, 2))
    Fs = 206850*Ec
    if Fs > 414:
        Fs = 414
    N = 62.9*Fc+1.6*Fs
    ws_template.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value = N

#Memorize file
wb.save(XLSFILE)
```

However, I can't conduct this program.

The error message is like this

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Cell' and 'float'
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Tips:

version: Python ver.3.6

Comment: `Ec` is a `Cell`, perhaps you might want to make use of its underlying value by passing `Ec.value` instead, i.e. try `(Ec.value/-0.002)`.  See [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do math on the value of the cell, not on the cell object

use `Ec.value` instead of `EC` or `Ec = ws_template.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value`

Comment: I can make it by using the code you showed me!

Comment: Excuse me. How should I accept your answer? I am not familiar with this site.

Comment: You can accept the answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +15 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle